# c++ api to get message md5sum from string msg type (e.g. std_msgs/Int32)

Tags: c++, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a c++ equivalent to retrieve the md5sum of a message type from the string msg type?

In python you can do:

```
import roslib
int32_msg_class = roslib.message.get_message_class('std_msgs/Int32');
int32_msg_md5sum = int32_msg_class._md5sum;
```

Is there a C++ API for doing the same?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88801/c++-api-to-get-message-md5sum-from-string-msg-type-(e.g.-std_msgs/int32)/) by [jbrindza](https://answers.ros.org/users/421/jbrindza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++ you can "ask" the message type instead of using an API like in Python.

```
#include "mypackage/MyMessage.h"
#include "ros/message_traits.h"
std::string md5sum = message_traits::md5sum<MyMessage>();
```

Since you need to have the message type for that at compile time this won't work when you have the message type as a string only.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbrindza](https://answers.ros.org/users/421/jbrindza/) on 2013-10-09**:
Thanks. That is what I thouhgt, just wanted to make sure it wasn't possible to do at runtime without a system call.